# How to send account confirmation e-mail after self sign up on WSO2 AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, email-validation, email-verification, api-manager

Hi i Want in API manager WSO2 in store section after user registered Send email with link to confirm account

am version: 2.5.0

Please Help Me

Comment: please post your work if you have done something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved through a custom workflow extension. By default there is a custom [workflow](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Adding+a+User+Signup+Workflow) to the user signup process. You may need to extend that to send an email. Please refer to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Customizing+a+Workflow+Extension).

Comment: I am sending email to the user after registering.
I Want to send him an email with a code to confirm his email
What can i do